# Kotlin coroutine:how to check a coroutine builder created a root coroutine

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

In the kotlin [coroutine exceptions doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#exception-propagation). The doc mentioned:

> When these builders are used to create a root coroutine, that is not a
> child of another coroutine

My question is how to check a coroutine scope is a not a child of another coroutine programmatically? I can not find any member function from `CoroutineScope` to indicate the current coroutine scope is a root coroutine or not.

**Edit**
In reality, is there a good way to find out what is root coroutine scope of a child scope by using Android Studio?

Comment: Why do you need this? It doesn't sound like something that we should ever check manually.

Comment: @broot, ok, then how to verify the manually check is right?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. My question was: why do you need to know if coroutine has a parent? If you really want to check this, you can use the debugger: `scope.coroutineContext[Job]!!.parentHandle.job` - this will give you a parent coroutine to the current one. `parentHandle` is internal, so you can only acquire it with the debugger or reflection. But this is internal stuff, we shouldn't care about it.